# What are alternative methods to using nested For loops?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through a row to see if a cells value is greater or less than the next cells value. If its greater, input the value as 1. If it is less, input the value as 0. The new 0 and 1 value are creating a new table and that is what I need the second For statement for, to loop through the new table and input the correct values.

I have tried nested for loops but it does not work.

```
For Each cel In Range("C748:BQ758")
    If cel.Value < cel.Next.Value Then
        For Each cel In Range("C904:BQ904")
            cel.Value = ClosedOutput
    ElseIf cel.Value > cel.Next.Value Then
        For Each cel In Range("C904:BQ904")
            cel.Value = OpenOutput
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: create two same sized variant arrays, one bulk loaded with the values from the range.  Loop that and test and place the value in the other similar size array then assign those value in bulk back to the new range area.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Also note that you are dealing exclusively with cases "greater than" and "smaller than" but I presume the cell values can be equal too?

Comment: Your inner loops are both missing a `Next` statement... is "does not work" a placeholder for a compile error?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mathieu Guindon in the comments you are missing the Next statements in the code. You are also using cel twice which (if i remember correctly) will mess things up, so you need to run two different variables. This is how it should look.

```
For Each Mcel In Range("C748:BQ758")
    If Mcel.Value < Mcel.Next.Value Then
        For Each Scel In Range("C904:BQ904")
            Scel.Value = ClosedOutput
        Next
    ElseIf Mcel.Value > cel.Next.Value Then
        For Each Scel In Range("C904:BQ904")
            Scel.Value = OpenOutput
        Next
    End If
Next cel
```

However you can reduce the number of For loops by one, by doing this:

```
For Each Mcel In Range("C748:BQ758")
    For Each Scel In Range("C904:BQ904")
        If Mcel.Value < cel.Next.Value Then
            Scel.Value = ClosedOutput
        Else
            'this allows for an equals to situation (you can change < to <= if you want it equal to the ClosedOutput value.
            Scel.Value = OpenOutput
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I like this answer because it is close to what I already had so it is still easy to understand. What this does though is loops through the entire range of C904:BP904 and places a value for each value in range C748:BP758. I want it to read a the values in C748 and D748 and then place a value in C904. Then read the values in D748 and E748 then put a value in C905 based on those values.

Comment: So basically loop 1, check C748 and D748, put value in C904, the D748 and E748 put value in C905?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, Use Variant arrays to speed things up:

```
Sub load()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet
        Dim ClosedOutput As Integer
        ClosedOutput = 0

        Dim OpenOutput As Integer
        OpenOutput = 1

        Dim inArr As Variant
        inArr = .Range("C748:BQ758")

        Dim outArr() As Variant
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(inArr, 1), 1 To UBound(inArr, 2))

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(inArr, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To UBound(inArr, 2) - 1
                If inArr(i, j) < inArr(i, j + 1) Then
                    outArr(i, j) = ClosedOutput
                Else
                    outArr(i, j) = OpenOutput
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        .Range("C904").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 1)).Value = outArr

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am very new at VBA so this is a bit confusing for me. What sort of works is this:For Each Mcel In Range("C748:BP758")
    If Mcel.Value <= Mcel.Next.Value Then
        For Each Scel In Range("C904:BP904")
            Scel.Value = ClosedOutput
        Next
    ElseIf Mcel.Value > Mcel.Next.Value Then
        For Each Scel In Range("C904:BP904")
            Scel.Value = OpenOutput
        Next
    End If
Next